# Should I implement __contains__ method when implementing Mapping or MutableMapping in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote a code for a custom dictionary using a list.
According to [collections.abc](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) module I only need to implement `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, `__len__` when impelementing `Mapping` and I did.
But a code include `in` statement which using `__contains__` methods inside seems always returns True.
Should I write `__contains__` method too?

```
from collections import Mapping


class ListDict(Mapping):

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = [] #  [(key, value)]

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        for k, v in self._data:
            if k == item:
                return v

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(e[0] for e in self._data)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)

d = ListDict()

print('key' in d) # True
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to handle the key-not-found case in your `__getitem__`. The provided `__contains__` implementation relies on `__getitem__` raising a `KeyError` for not-present keys. Your `__getitem__` is broken, so the provided `__contains__` breaks too.

Raise a `KeyError`:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    for k, v in self._data:
        if k == item:
            return v
    raise KeyError(item)
```

Comment: docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details although, not sure if this is clear in here, because at least when I read it, I would think that it would first defer to `__iter__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: That's the default behavior of `in` if `__contains__` isn't provided, but `collections.Mapping` provides a `__contains__` implementation in terms of `__getitem__`.

Comment: aha! Then it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - `__getitem__` returned `None` which is a valid object. In this implementation, the container holds all things and they are `None`.

Comment: @tdelaney no, yes, I understood that, what I wasn't grokking was that if `__contains__` isn't implemented, then a user-defined object should first defer to iterating, comparing each item using first `is` then `==`.  However, I totally overlooked that `Mapping` *implements `__contains__`*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - sorry, I should have removed the tag to you. I wrote the comment but peeked at the source to verify before posting and catching up with the rest of the thread.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought `in` relys on `__iter__`.